# Android HTTP GET request to MongoLab

Tags: android, rest, httprequest, mlab

I'm developing a test application in a sand-box db at `MongoLab`.
When executing a REST query I get the correct document, but executing the same in my Android app throw exception:

Query:
`https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-col?q={id:"123"}&apiKey=***`
(of course the db,col and api key are defined).
Putting this URI in the browser gets back the document I'm looking for.

Android:

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        Log.i("URI", uri[0]);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                responseString = out.toString();
                out.close();
            } else {
                // Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, result);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 71: https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-col?q={"id":"123"}&apiKey=***
```

The char at index 71 is the first `=` after `my-col?q`, and there is a reference to this line:
`response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));`

Why is it working well on the browser and not on my device?
I have successfully pulled all the documents without a query though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the URL directly to the client, it won't be encoded automatically.

Try to encode it with `URLEncoder.encode(yourParameter, "UTF-8")` or use a querybuilder and the `appendQueryParameter` method from `android.net.Uri.Builder`.